# Slim PHP: make $app available in classes

Tags: php, class, slim

I'm using controller/method as callbacks to application routes.

E.g.:

```
$app->get('/user/login', array('User', 'login'));
```

Here is the sample `User` class:

```
Class User {
  public function login() {
    print 'Login page.';
  }
}
```

How can I make the `$app` variable available automatically in all classes?
I know I can get it using `getInstance()` method, but I need to call it manually every time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a base class that provides common elements and extend that base class in each of your controllers. Here is an example base class:

```
class BaseController { 
   $app = new YourApp();

    function __construct() {
           $this->app->get('/user/login', array('User', 'login'));

}
```

Then, you can extend that class you your controller to get access to `$app`:

```
class User extends BaseController {

    function yourFunction() {
        // $this->app is already set!
}
```

**Update to parameterize the route:**

In BaseController:

```
function __construct($route) {
       $this->app->get($route, array('User', 'login'));
```

Then include the route parameter when you initialize your class:

```
$user = new User('/user/login');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure I understand completely - can you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks again, it's clear now. Is there any way I can keep the routes outside of BaseController or it has to be done that way?

Comment: You can provide the route as a parameter to your controllers and set it in the constructor. I'll update my answer with a brief example.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. I get the direction now. Thank you very much for your help George :)

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: Sorry, only saw your note about not wanting to call getInstance() afterwards. I'll leave my initial answer here as reference in either case.*

You can simply call the getInstance() method: `$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();`

Since November 2013 you may now use a controller class instance as a callback for your Slim app routes (and their parameters) via functionality called "[Class Controllers](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/releases/tag/2.4.0)":

```
$app->map('/foo/:bar/:baz', '\Foo:fun')->via('GET', 'POST');
```

Getting an instance of $app in the callback class instance is easy enough:

```
class Foo {
    public function fun($var1, $var2) {
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    }
}
```